# Как работать в bs4 с такими классами страниц (python)

Tags: bs4

class="sc-qQyIJ llBNMF" Вот такое класс на странице, я хочу оттуда спарсить информацию с помощью bs4, но мне вечно в консоли выводит none, не понимаю что за классы... подскажите люди добрые

Comment: bs4 с динамическими именами вряд ли справится, пользуйте selenium

Comment: Я уже парсил так, но мне не нравится, что браузер вечно открывается...